# GC selection for Java/Netty file upload REST service

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, garbage-collection, netty

I have a Java REST service which runs on Netty and is used for uploading(streaming) large number of files of 5MB to 500MB. When I'm increasing the number of concurrent uploads at some point the application goes out of memory, which is expected, but I'm looking for recommendations on which Java GC and VM settings should I use in this scenario to improve the performance and to reduce the memory footprint.
I would really appreciate if somebody could share similar experiences.

**UPDATE:** To add more context to the question, the REST service is getting file as a stream and passing the same stream to Amazon S3.

Comment: It is not at all obvious why you'd get OOME. A properly coded application would not do that. You gave no code or any other clues as to your imlementation.

Comment: Is increasing max heap not an option? It seems like you should allow the VM to allocate more memory if you want to use more memory.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Marko. If you are trying to send 100 simultaneous requests(streams) and each of them has a 100MB file, what is the expected behavior for a "properly coded" application considering the fact that you are testing on a single server with 2GB of RAM?

Comment: Thanks Dev. I'm trying to find GC and JVM configurations which can get the most out of the allocated resources for the type of the application I described.

Comment: @Frank: I guess a "properly coded" application would work fine as there's no reason for keeping all the data in memory. IIUYC the files get copied from the disk to the net, so you don't need anything but some small buffer per file. A buffer like 8kB should do, more can be better, but even with 1MB per file there should be a lot of memory left.

Comment: Thanks @maaartinus. Maybe my explanation of the service is a little confusing. My service is basically just a transport layer between the client (which uploads files) and Amazon S3. I'm just passing the InputStream which I get from the client to Amazon S3, so there is no disk involved in this process.

Comment: I see. I'd say just make sure you don't buffer too much data. Or somebody else (Netty) doesn't as Igor Alelekov wrote. This would be trivial if you'd handle the data yourself, but with passing streams, it's opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you should use a flow control when sending large data amount. You can check if the channel is writable (Channel.isWritable()) before sending data and wait untill it will be ready. You can use notifications via ChannelInboundHandler.channelWritabilityChanged(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) to track this. Without flow control all your large files will consume memory waiting for sending in Netty's output buffer.

Comment: Thanks @Igor! I'll take a look at the classes you mentioned.